# Cannot run PIP3 in MacBook Air M1

Tags: pip, apple-m1

**Background**: I just got this new MacBook Air M1. I installed ITerm2 and when asked if I wanted to install the dev package I did it.

**Problem**: I cannot run Pip3. When I try I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder
ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index' (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/__init__.py)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ImportError%3A+cannot+import+name+%22PackageFinder%22

Answer (score 0):

try [reinstalling pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py
```

and when you are done

```
$ rm get-pip.py
```

Comment: if you use conda or venv, first remove pip folders from site-packages